# Posting with UIActivityViewController, but avoiding cropping?

Tags: swift3, share, instagram, uiactivityviewcontroller

Say you construct an image that is fullscreen on different devices.  You then use UIActivityViewController to post to - for example - Instagram in the normal way.

The user clicks your share button, it brings up the usual iOS-sharing-thingy,

[image]

and you can post to Instagram (assuming the user's an Instagram user of course).  No worries.

But typically the image is cropped on Instagram - you lose a little of the top and bottom.

Is there actually any solution for this?

Note that indeed - say you open the normal Photos app on the iPhone, and "share" and post on Instagram ... **you lose a little of the top and bottom**!

When the user does click the Instagram icon on this ...

[image]

in fact is there a way for me then to ***go back, be aware of the user's choice, and make the image the appropriate size***?

Is there perhaps a way to ***pass a selection of images (various sizes)*** to the UIActivityViewController?

What's the deal on this, it seems like a basic failing?

Note - I'm fully aware that BEFORE going to the iOS-share-thingy, I could ask the user myself "What size image would you like me to make?"

Note - I'm aware that it's in some cases possible to post "directly" to say Instagram inside the app, without using Apple's share system; that's lame though.

To save anyone typing, here's some clean code to bring up the iOS-share system...

```
    @IBAction func userClickedOurShareButton()
        {
        let s:[AnyObject] = [buildImage()]
        let ac = CleanerActivity(activityItems:s, applicationActivities:nil)

        ac.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        // needed so that iPads won't crash. sarcasm: thanks Apple

        ac.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.assignToContact,
            UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
            UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
            UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard ]

        // consider UIActivityTypeMessage also

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                ac.excludedActivityTypes?.append(UIActivityType.openInIBooks)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }

        self.present(ac, animated:false, completion:nil)
        }


class CleanerActivity: UIActivityViewController {

    func _shouldExcludeActivityType(_ activity: UIActivity) -> Bool {
        let activityTypesToExclude = [
            "com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension",
            "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension",
            "com.google.Drive.ShareExtension",
            "com.apple.mobileslideshow.StreamShareService"
        ]

        if let actType = activity.activityType {
            if activityTypesToExclude.contains(actType.rawValue) {
                return true
            }
            else if super.excludedActivityTypes != nil {
                return super.excludedActivityTypes!.contains(actType)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer: this solution involves hard-coding Instagram's extension identifier into your app, which may or may not make it through app review, and may break in the future. Try at your own risk!**

Apple provides a mechanism for this called `UIActivityItemProvider`. Instead of passing an image to your `UIActivityViewController`, you can pass subclass of `UIActivityItemProvider` that overrides `itemForActivityType` to return an appropriate image based on the activity type chosen by the user.

Apple provides constants for many common activity types, but Instagram isn't yet included. You can identify Instagram by checking if the activity type's raw value is `com.burbn.instagram.shareextension`. This would break if Instagram changed the ID of their extension.

Here's an `UIActivityItemProvider` that provides different images to Instagram:

```
class DynamicImageProvider: UIActivityItemProvider {

    let instagramImage: UIImage
    let defaultImage: UIImage

    init(instagramImage: UIImage, defaultImage: UIImage) {
        self.instagramImage = instagramImage
        self.defaultImage = defaultImage
        super.init(placeholderItem: defaultImage)
    }

    override func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController,
                                         itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
        if activityType.rawValue == "com.burbn.instagram.shareextension" {
            return instagramImage
        }
        else {
            return defaultImage
        }
    }
}
```

Then change the first two lines of your IBAction:

```
let imageProvider = DynamicImageProvider(instagramImage:buildInstagramImage(), defaultImage:buildImage())
let ac = CleanerActivity(activityItems:[imageProvider], applicationActivities:nil)
```

Comment: Thanks again. I'm not 100% sure if this is what I need but your knowledge is so rare that I sent over the bounty to say thanks, Toadster!

Comment: My github has lots of forks from when I needed to modify something, standing on the darn cool shoulders of giants ;) Thanks for the bounty and hope it helped!

Comment: hey!  you may know the answer to this nuisance question, Toadster ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841095/avlayervideogravityresize-does-not-match-on-new-devices-ios-10  Cheers.

Comment: @charmingToad Hi I need help related to share images on instagram using my app. Please help me.